# <input text> não funciona no Firefox dentro de um echo em php

Tags: php

sabem me dizer como posso fazer um input funcionar no firefox? coloco dessa forma dentro de um echo, mas não digita nada...o que pode ser?

```
echo '<fieldset>';
echo '<input id="name" type="text" class="form-control join-form" placeholder="Insira aqui o seu CEP">';
echo '</fieldset>';
echo '<font size="5" color="black"><span>* Digitar somente números no CEP</span></font>';
echo '<br />';
echo '<span id="value"></span>';
```

Comment: Tens a certeza que essa linha de código está a ser corrida?

Comment: não saiu tudo..

Comment: no meu resultou, qual é o servidor local que vc ta usando?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá,

Está faltando o atributo name='cep' para que o POST seja reconhecido.

Por exemplo:

```
echo '<fieldset>';
echo '<input id="cep" name="cep" type="text" class="form-control join-form" placeholder="Insira aqui o seu CEP">';
echo '</fieldset>';
echo '<font size="5" color="black"><span>* Digitar somente números no CEP</span></font>';
echo '<br />';
echo '<span id="value"></span>';
```